# How to respond to `apple-app-site-association` requests

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I see `404 not found` errors in my log files because of a missing `/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` file.

As far as I understand the purpose of that file is to tell iOS devices what applications to consider to communicate with the server. But my website is a completely static website and doesn't have an iOS application published.

I wonder what is the appropriate response to such a request?

- Just keep the `404 not found`? Because that file doesn't make sense in the context of a static, non-interactive website when there isn't an iOS application available apart from normal web browsers.
- Or this there some kind of empty or default `apple-app-site-association` file that should be returned instead of a `404 not found`? It feels to me that this might makes sense, because when I know that an iOS device is querying for that file then should return at least *something* - like a `robots.txt` that just tells that nothing is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think iOS devices query for the file, Apples robot does so that it can build an index of the contents and mappings to apps. It's possible spotlight / safari might query it on demand, not sure. This is part of deep linking / spotlight search. I wouldn't worry about it at all if you don't have an app.

Answer (score 0):

iOS devices will attempt to load this file if an application explicitly specifies your domain. It would be unusual indeed if an app was requesting your domain without your knowledge, so probably not a situation worth worrying about.

More likely this is either applebot or googlebot performing a regular indexing operation. Both Apple and Google now use the apple-app-site-association file to check if your site contains app content, so they appear to be checking for it as a regular part of the crawling process. Of course, there is no official documentation about this!

Returning 404 is the expected failure state, as far as I know. This is a file that should only be present on an opt-in basis.

Comment: what if we place empty file ? @alex-bauer

Comment: I would expect that also to fail, since the file must be both present and valid to actually do anything. But why would you return an empty file?

Answer (score 0):

Imo, if you don't have an iOS app then responding to `.well-known/apple-app-site-association` is pretty much irrelevant.
All it's supposed to have are your apple app bundle ids and route informations for enabling universal links, authorisation, and all that jazz.

It's like `robots.txt` but for the Apple eco system only.

---

More Reading:

- https://www.nccgroup.trust/uk/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blogs/2019/april/apples-app-site-association-the-new-robots.txt/